# Go : socket library to get hostname

Tags: sockets, go, websocket

Is there any equivalent to python socket library in Go?
https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

I want to do something like this in Go:

```
import socket
ip = socket.gethostbyname(domain + ".multi.surbl.org")
# Translate a host name to IPv4 address format.
```

What package can I use to do this in Go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [net namespace](http://golang.org/pkg/net/) contains methods to translate hostnames to IP addresses (and a few other calls similar to what's in the Python `socket` namespace)

The call you're probably looking for is [net.LookupHost](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#LookupHost) or [net.LookupIP](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#LookupIP);

```
addrs, err := net.LookupHost(hostname)
```